# Imagem por cima de outra como um carimbo usando css

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma imagem na tela onde quero adicionar um carimbo, o problema é que como esta imagem está dentro de um foreach, então se eu pegar o id da imagem, vai esta repetido.

```css
#carimbo-foto{
   position:absolute;
   z-index:0
}


#carimbo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left:-64px;
    margin-top:-73px;  
    z-index:1
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="carimbo-foto">
        <img src=~/Content/imagens/carimbo.jpg class="img-responsive" id="carimbo" alt="" width="128" height="128">
        <img src=~/Content/imagembanner/@item.LOCALIMAGEM class="img-responsive" id="banner" alt=@item.DESCRICAO width="560" height="315">
    </div>
</div>
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu não entendi direito o problema..você está usando alguma função em JQuery para isso?

Comment: A minha dúvida é sobre a possibilidade de adicionar um carimbo na imagem, para que o carimbo sempre fique dentro da imagem do banner, este carimbo eu quero que ao clicar em salvar a imagem ele venha junto.

Comment: Entendi @itasouza, meu palpite é que você vai precisar mesclar as imagens para criar somente uma. Talvez exista apis para isso.

Comment: Dá uma olhada nisso: http://brianium.github.io/watermarkjs/.